# Sublime Text 3 filesearch exclude specific pattern

Tags: sublimetext3

When using `CTRL` + `P` to search in all project-files in Sublime Text 3, I use the following settings to exclude some folders:

```
    "binary_file_patterns": 
[
    ".svn/**",
    ".git/**",
    ".hg",
    "node_modules/**",
    "bower_components",
    "cache",
    "deprecated",
    "vendor/**"
]
```

Is it possible to exclude all `vendor` content **but not** the `vendor/laravel` folder? Is there any form of regular expressions possible or are there some negating operators that I could use?

Answer (score 1):

The key to exclude folders is `folder_exclude_pattern`, but there's also a corresponding`folder_include_pattern`. Try this:

```
{
    "folder_exclude_pattern": [ "vendor" ],
    "folder_include_pattern": [ "vendor/laravel"]
}
```

Comment: The exclude worked with the plural "patterns", but when i exclude the 'vendor' folder, then its gone and the include doesnt do anything.